# Grabbing headers from webpage with python

Tags: python, html, http, python-3.x

How can I use python 3 to get access to the HTTP Headers. Specifically, I am trying to recreate the headers you can gain access to through network in the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: @Vladiki Would you please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import urllib.request
>>> u = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(u.getheaders()))
{'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
 'Connection': 'close',
 'Content-Length': '18882',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html',
 'Date': 'Sat, 24 Dec 2011 23:51:27 GMT',
 'ETag': '"105800d-49c2-4b4ab1ba443c0"',
 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 22 Dec 2011 09:41:43 GMT',
 'Server': 'Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)',
 'X-Pad': 'avoid browser bug'}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out what I needed. Found a work-around so that I don't need headers